# Do I need to bother with INLINE/INLINABLE pragmas for small, exported, functions, or will GHC do it for me?

Tags: haskell, optimization, inline, ghc

I have a module which collects and exports a bunch of small functions such as:

```
fromEither :: (MonadError e m) => Either e a -> m a
fromEither = either throwError return
```

or

```
withError :: MonadError e m => (e -> e) -> m a -> m a
withError = flip catchError (throwError . f)
```

It's a good idea to have them inlined, as after specializing to a particular instance of `MonadError` it's likely a lot of code will be optimized away.

The GHC's documentation says:

> GHC (with `-O`, as always) tries to inline (or “unfold”) functions/values that are “small enough,” thus avoiding the call overhead and possibly exposing other more-wonderful optimisations. Normally, if GHC decides a function is “too expensive” to inline, it will not do so, nor will it export that unfolding for other modules to use.

Does it mean that such functions are most likely to be treated as if they had an `INLINE` pragma (i.e. their non-optimised RHS recorded in the interface file)? Or do I have to add `INLINE` myself? Does adding it change anything (assuming GHC decides they're "small enough")?

I don't mind if GHC decides not to inline some of my functions, if it feels they're too expensive, but in general I'd like to have them inlined without polluting my source code with adding `INLINE` everywhere.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From my experience, such small functions will be inlined automatically and across module borders, if it makes sense.

You can check whether GHC decided to make that possible, by running `ghc --show-iface` on the resulting `.hi`-File. If it says something about an `Unfolding` as in the follwing example, when using this module the function will likely be inlined:

```
$ ghc --show-iface /usr/lib/ghc/base-4.6.0.1/Data/Either.hi
Magic: Wanted 33214052,
       got    33214052
...
38da29044ff77a85b08cebca1fed11ad
  either :: forall a c b.
            (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> Data.Either.Either a b -> c
    {- Arity: 3, HasNoCafRefs, Strictness: LLS,
       Unfolding: (\ @ a
                     @ c
                     @ b
                     f :: a -> c
                     ds :: b -> c
                     ds1 :: Data.Either.Either a b ->
                   case ds1 of wild {
                     Data.Either.Left x -> f x Data.Either.Right y -> ds y }) -}
```

Answer (score 6):

I want to add to Joachim's answer that the number of functions in the module also influences whether or not `ghc` will export them.  For example, `Pipes.Prelude` from `pipes` would show slow-downs on several functions when I started to add several unrelated functions to the same module.  Adding `INLINABLE` pragmas to these functions restored their original speed.

Comment: If it were the pure number of functions, I’d find that surprising... have you verified that it is the number, and not some other effect?

Comment: I have verified that adding more unrelated exported functions triggers this effect.  I haven't proven that this is a direct or indirect consequence of the number of functions.

Comment: Sorry for being doubtful, but I cannot find any such code in `TidyPgm`, where the decision about adding an unfolding is made (`show_unfolding` in `addExternal`). There must have been some other effect triggered by the change.